# R condensing dataframe based on logic

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
dframe = data.frame(SiteCode = c(1,2,2,3,4,4),
                    SiteName= c('A','B','B','C','D','D'),
                    Revenue= c(100,200,200,550,700,700),
                    StrategicSite=c('Yes','No','No','No','Yes','Yes'),
                    Email=c('Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No'))
```

It has information on 4 client sites, and the final column `Email` determines whether the client should be emailed a promotion or not.

For sites `B` and `D`, there is an anomaly I'd like to correct. Their `Email` columns contain both `Yes` and `No`. I'd like to write a code such that in case there is a `No` and `Yes` status in the `Email` column for the same client site, the `Email` column always becomes a `Yes`. Thereby eliminating the duplicate.

The resulting dataframe would look like this -

```
desired_result = data.frame(SiteCode = c(1,2,3,4),
                           SiteName= c('A','B','C','D'),
                           Revenue= c(100,200,550,700),
                           StrategicSite=c('Yes','No','No','Yes'),
                           Email=c('Yes','Yes','No','Yes'))
```

I used `dplyr` in my attempt, but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for

```
my_attempt = dframe %>% group_by(SiteCode,SiteName,Revenue,StrategicSite) %>%
  mutate(Email = ifelse(Email=='Yes','Yes',Email))
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you should use `case_when()` inside mutate, and then `any(Email == "yes") as the condition. Finally,` distinct()` removes duplicates.

```
library(dplyr)
dframe %>%
  group_by(SiteCode,SiteName,Revenue,StrategicSite) %>%
  mutate(Email = case_when(any(Email == "Yes") ~ "Yes",
                           TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
  distinct()
```

Comment: Why not using `summarise()`? It can save you the use of `distinct()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `summarize` instead of `mutate`:

```
dframe %>% 
  group_by(SiteCode, SiteName, Revenue, StrategicSite) %>%
  summarize(Email = ifelse("Yes" %in% Email, 'Yes', Email)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  SiteCode SiteName Revenue StrategicSite Email
     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>         <chr>
1        1 A            100 Yes           Yes  
2        2 B            200 No            Yes  
3        3 C            550 No            No   
4        4 D            700 Yes           Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `unique` + `ave`

```
unique(within(dframe,Email <- ave(Email,SiteCode,SiteName,Revenue,StrategicSite,FUN = function(x) ifelse("Yes"%in%x,"Yes","No"))))
```

which gives

```
  SiteCode SiteName Revenue StrategicSite Email
1        1        A     100           Yes   Yes
2        2        B     200            No   Yes
4        3        C     550            No    No
5        4        D     700           Yes   Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base` R solution with `aggregate()`. It's advantage is that you can use `"."` in the formula to represent all columns except `Email`.

```
aggregate(Email ~ ., dframe, function(x) ifelse("Yes" %in% x, "Yes", "No"))

#   SiteCode SiteName Revenue StrategicSite Email
# 1        2        B     200            No   Yes
# 2        3        C     550            No    No
# 3        1        A     100           Yes   Yes
# 4        4        D     700           Yes   Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option

```
dframe %>% group_by(SiteCode,SiteName,Revenue,StrategicSite) %>%arrange(desc(Email))%>%filter(row_number()==1)%>%arrange(SiteName)
```

This will provide exactly what you want.